# Drop constraint returned by select query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a migration script to drop a constraint that has different names in different environments

**Drop this constraint:**

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY custom_data
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_d86d725d64
    FOREIGN KEY (custom_id) REFERENCES customs(id);
```

**I'd like to do something like this:** (but it doesn't work)

```
alter table custom_data
drop constraint (
    SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'custom_data'
    AND COLUMN_NAME =  'custom_id')
```

Is there another way to rephrase above so it might work? Or could someone help me understand why the above doesn't work?

### UPDATE

Also trying to use `do` but its not working either. The constraint still exists when I check.

```
do $$
    declare c_name text;
    begin
        select constraint_name into c_name
        from information_schema.key_column_usage
        where table_name = 'custom_data' and 
            column_name = 'custom_id';

      execute format ('alter table custom_data drop constraint %I', c_name);
    end;
$$;
```

If running the select statement,

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'custom_data'
AND COLUMN_NAME =  'custom_id'
```

Sometimes the result is,

```
 | constraint_name
_|____________________
1| fk_rails_d86d725d64
```

But sometimes the result is,

```
 | constraint_name
_|____________________
1|
```

When running the big query to get the constraint and remove it,

Sometimes the result is,

```
Empty query string
```

But sometimes the result is,

```
Name         | Value
_____________|___________
Query        | do
Updated Rows | 0
Finish time  | Tue Mar 21...
```

Its starting to seem like a bad whitespace issue to me now...

Could this also be impacted by the column already having an index as well?

```
CREATE INDEX index_custom_data_on_custom_id ON custom_data USING btree (custom_id);
```

Comment: The dynamic SQL should work. Maybe you forgot to commit the `alter table`? Also: do not include the `;` in the dynamic SQL string (but I don't think it matters)

Comment: Do you get any error upon executing the `do` statement? Are you sure `custom_data` is in the `search_path` when you run it?

Comment: @pozs. Updated question with the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change:

```
select constraint_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where table_name = 'custom_data' and 
      column_name = 'custom_id';
```

To:

```
select constraint_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where table_name = 'custom_data' and column_name = 'custom_id';
```

I guess it was a whitespace issue. Appreciated all the help in the comments.